# Equal separation between south of one node and north of another

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, boxes, nodes

I am new to TikZ and am trying to get these three boxes with equal spacings between the *outer frames* of the boxes such that the two arrows are the same length. I am going to have a flow chart with lots of boxes and would like all arrows the same length. If anyone could tell me how to do this I would be very grateful! Here is my code:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=8cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 4cm]

\node [block] (1) {There is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this nodeThere is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this node,};
\node [block, below of=1] (2) {not in this};
\node [block, below of=2] (3) {nor in this};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site Elly. It's better, by the way, if you include the `\documentclass ... \end{document}` stuff as well, as it saves people having to type it out when they copy your code into their text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably isn't the *best* way to do it, but one thing you *could* do is replace the `node distance` with `below=4cm of 1` and so on. You need to load the `positioning` library if you want to use the `below=<distance> of <node>` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=8cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block] (1) {There is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this nodeThere is a lot of writing in this node, There is a lot of writing in this node,};
\node [block, below=2cm of 1] (2) {not in this};
\node [block, below=2cm of 2] (3) {nor in this};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your speedy reply, but for some reason this does not seem to work for me, even though I have put in \usetikzlibrary{positioning}. I get the boxes on top of each other with no space between, and when I increase 2cm to 10cm it makes no difference at all..?

Comment: It looks to me like the message in the log is the same as the for other packages which do work- there is one line that refers to it:             (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex)

Comment: Sorry about delay - I have now upgraded TexLive and your first answer works! Thanks so much!

Comment: Excellent `:-)`. Now let's tidy up this page for the benefit of future visitors. Can you delete your comments above? I'll delete mine too.